# Metric tensor $g$ of level set map $f = 0$ on manifold $\mathcal{M}$

Tags: differential-geometry

I am an engineering student with an interest in differential geometry. During a robotics class, I made myself the question: How would a robot walk over an algebraic surface? Before I go into robot modeling, which robotic engineering is good at, I must model the surface. We can implicitly model smooth surfaces by algebraic equalities of type $f(x) = 0$, for some point $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

However, It is not straightforward to me how to obtain the metric tensor $\tilde g$ of such implicit parametrization. I suppose it relates to the Pullback metric concept of the following concept: given by map $\mathbb{D}_f \stackrel{f}{\to} \mathbb{R}^n$, we define the metric $g$ on map $f$ root locus $S$ by the pullback metric $f^*g$.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your surface is a submanifold $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, one can define a metric on $S$ using your chosen metric on $\mathbb{R}^3.$ If $\rho$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and we have an immersion $\iota: S \to \mathbb{R}^3$ bringing $S$ into $\mathbb{R}^3,$ then $\iota^*\rho$ is a metric on $S.$ In your case, since $S$ is defined inside $\mathbb{R}^3$ and not abstractly, you could choose the simplest immersion $\iota(x) = x.$

The expression $f^*\rho$ doesn't make sense assuming this is the same $f$ that defines $S$ implicitly. That is because $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ which implies $f^*$ takes linear maps operating on vectors of $\mathbb{R}$ to linear maps operating on tangent vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3.$ The metric tensor is a bilinear map on $\mathbb{R}^3,$ and really all you need to do is restrict its operation to only $S$ and vectors tangent to $S.$ So you require some map going from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ that will pullback this bilinear map. The immersion will do the job.

Comment: I am not familiar how to handle algebraicly an immersion in this roleplay. My second guess would be to (instead of using equality $f = 0$): to extend 1 dimension by making $y = f: \mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{R}$; pullback $f^*g$ of metric $1$ over real line $\mathbb{R}$, equal to natural 1. Does it work as well?

Comment: What you are describing does not sound correct and I would not expect it to work. But there is something similar that does work. The practical approach locally is to define a local slice coordinate chart for $S$ induced in part by $f = 0$ --- say, define $\xi := f(x)$ --- and your choice of remaining coordinates $\eta^1$ and $\eta^2.$ Write your metric in these coordinates, and the pullback onto $S$ is just setting $\xi = 0$ and $d\xi=0.$

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto to clarify why I would not expect it to work: the pullback of the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ onto the manifold is not going to be a metric, because the pullback you describe necessarily has a non-trivial kernel (your surface and $\mathbb{R}^3$ have a higher dimension) so one would expect the pulled back 2-tensor will fail to be positive definite.

Comment: This is sad. Have you read the article abstract I just forwarded you in another question?

Comment: *Correction to my comment. The pushforward has a kernel. The pullback doesn't have a kernel but fails to be injective and that is why it fails to be pos.def.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto, yes. Indeed my area is nonlinear control theory. If you want to discuss something off-topic from the question, might I suggest a [stack chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com)? Just to avoid cluttering question space.

Comment: What about the pullback of map $(X, y(X)): \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M} \times \mathbb{R}$, for X the position vector also known as exponential map?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138422/discussion-between-rollen-s-dsouza-and-bruno-peixoto).